# Not able to set the Text Value of a Label in A RadGrid EditTemplate column

Tags: gridview, telerik, radgrid, radgridview

I am having a problem showing the asp dropdownlist selected value in a Telerik RadGrid EditItemTemplate Column in edit mode.  When I go into edit mode on a row the selected value for the drop down is not being shown.  The dropdown works it just does not show the current data.  Below is my RadGrid column layout.

```
<Columns>
                                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ContactID" HeaderText="ContactID" ReadOnly="true" UniqueName="ContactID" AllowFiltering="false"
                                        DataType="System.Int16" DefaultInsertValue="" Exportable="false" Visible="false">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Contact" HeaderText="Contact" SortExpression="Contact" UniqueName="Contact"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="ContactTemplateColumn" HeaderText="Contact Type">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Contact" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Contact") %>'>
                                            </asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlContacts" runat="server" DataTextField="ContactType" DataValueField="ContactTypeID"></asp:DropDownList>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Delete this contact?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow"
                                        ConfirmTitle="Delete" ButtonType="ImageButton" ImageUrl="~/Images/filterCancel.gif" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" Exportable="false" />
                                </Columns>
```

I have placed the code behind shown below in the RAdGrid_ItemCommand method with the plan being when the edit form was rendered the selected value for the Role would be displayed in the Label.  However I am getting an error message ""Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I think the problem is I am not finding the the label User Control.

```
if (ItemCommand == "Edit")
        {

            using (ExpungeEntities db = new ExpungeEntities())
            {
                var editableItem = ((GridEditableItem)e.Item);
                var strUserId = (int)editableItem.GetDataKeyValue("UserID");
                var d = db.USERS_T_DATA.SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserID == strUserId);
                string strRole = d.Role;
                (editableItem.FindControl("lblRole") as Label).Text = strRole.Trim();

            }

        }
```

Can someone help me out and provide a solution as to how I can show the selected value for an ASP dropdown list in the EditItemTemplate?

Comment: Sorry, can you edit your post? The aspx code does not seem right. And where is your dropdownlist?

Comment: @AlexandruPopa thanks for your response.  I have found the solution and will post it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandruPopa I have edited my post and show all of the columns now.  The answer shown below is for a different situation and is not correct for this problem.  The one below is for binding a drop down

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was applying the code in the wrong location.  I needed to put it in the ONItemDataBound method.  I could then bind the drop down list.  I also had to add code to show the selected value for an existing record in the same method.  See the code that works for my situation below.

```
 protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
        {
            //populate the drop down list
            using (ExpungeEntities db = new ExpungeEntities())
            {
                var roles = db.Roles.Select(r => new { r.RoleData, r.RoleText }).ToList();
                GridEditableItem item2 = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
                DropDownList list = item2.FindControl("ddlRole") as DropDownList;
                list.DataTextField = "RoleText";
                list.DataValueField = "RoleData";
                list.DataSource = roles;
                list.DataBind();

            }
            // Show the current role assigned from the database
            GridEditableItem item = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlRole");
            ddl.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Role").ToString();

        }


    }
```

Comment: I am not having a problem binding the dropdown or getting the new value when I update the record.  My problem occurs in the On Item Update command.  It finds the Dropdown control but does not seem to be able to find the Label control.